# How to create a type in Clojure from an input of Strings for symbol names?

Tags: clojure, symbols, deftype

I'm trying to create a list of types - so that I can map over a list of Strings and create all the types I need.

This is where I'm aiming for:

```
(defprotocol P (methodname [arg1]))

(deftype T [f] P (methodname [arg1] (println "methodname called")))
```

For just a single instance of generating a type from String names - I'm trying:

```
(defmacro create-type [type-name field-list protocol-name protocol-sig]
  `(deftype ~type-name ~field-list ~protocol-name ~protocol-sig))

(create-type (symbol "type-name") [field1]  (symbol "P") (methodname [arg1]))
```

This fails with:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Symbol  clojure.core/ns-resolve (core.clj:4026)
```

My question is: **How to create a type in Clojure from an input of Strings for symbol names?**

Comment: Wrong parenthesis closing or am I missing something? Note that `[field1])` closes parenthesis, so whole list is actually `(create-type (symbol "type-name") [field1])`

Comment: Thanks - fixed up - underlying problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit hacky, but works for me:

```
(defprotocol P (methodname [arg1]))`

(defmacro gen-type [type-name field-list proto-name proto-sig]
`(load-string (str "(deftype " ~type-name " " ~(str field-list) ~(str proto-name) ~(str proto-sig) ")")))

(gen-type "T" [f1 f2] P (methodname [arg1]))
```

So I'm just basically building a string and evaluate that with the reader.

Without load-string (still not too flexible, but does the job):

```
(defmacro gentype [t f p m a b]
  `(deftype ~(symbol t) ~f ~p (~m ~a ~b)))

(gentype "T3" [f1 f2] P methodname [arg1] (prn arg1))
```

Comment: Appreciate the can-do attitude. This is definitely a fall-back. I just wish there was a solution that didn't involve `read-string` :)

Comment: I think I know how to do this, I'll edit my answer soon.